# JavaScript generator function times out when trying to replicate Python's itertools.combinations

Tags: javascript, python, ecmascript-6, combinations, permutation

With the help of a couple of answers here I've been able to start learning about generators and develop the following function:

```
function* icombinations(arr, k) {

  function* getCombinations(newArr, shift) {
    if (newArr.length === k) {
      yield newArr;
    }

    for (let i = shift; i < arr.length; i++) {
      yield* getCombinations([...newArr, arr[i]], i + 1);
    }
  }

  yield* getCombinations([], 0);

  return [];
}
```

Here is a link to repl.it: https://repl.it/E2QW/1

I haven't probably grasped the concept fully since the function above times out for very long inputs as I'm trying to generate all possible combinations first and then yield each one. Would you know how I could refactor the the function so that I don't generate all combinations first?

Here is the description of the challenge that I'm trying to solve:

> Write a function called `icombinations` that should be a generator function with behavior similar to
>   Python's itertools.combinations. You are given an array `arr` of unique
>   items and an integer `k`.
>
> You should yield each unique combination of elements in `arr` of length
>   `k` with no replacements until  there are no possible unique
>   combinations left, at which point you should terminate the generator 
>   function. Your generator will be called with `next()`, and in some cases
>   it will be called until  completion.
>
> Additionally It is important that you return combinations in the same
>   order as the original array `arr`. (see the example below)....
>
> For example:
>
> given an array of unique elements `example_arr` and an integer
>   `example_k`:
>
> where `example_arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `example_k = 2`;
>
> calling the `next()` method of the iterator should return `[ 'a', 'b' ]`.
>
> if we were to call `next()` again we should get `[ 'a', 'c' ]` and so
>   on...
>
> so that if we got all values yielded by the generator we would have
>   the following:
>
> `[ 'a', 'b' ] [ 'a', 'c' ] [ 'a', 'd' ] [ 'b', 'c' ] [ 'b', 'd' ] [
>   'c', 'd' ]` again, notice the order of the above, as you will need to
>   replicate it in your solution.
>
> Some more things to consider:
>
> If your solution is timing out, it may be because you tried to
>   generate all possible combinations first and then yield each one. 
>   This defeats the point of a generator. Some of input values will be
>   large.
>
> Values in `arr` will always be unique but they may be of different types
>   (i.e. strings, integers, other objects).
>
> The only cases in which you would not be able to produce combinations
>   is that in which `arr` is null or empty or has a length less than `k`. In
>   any of those situations you should return an empty array.

Comment: Don't generate them all first; that's kind of the point of having a generator.  Your description explicitly says this (first "thing to consider").

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've re-read in a couple of times and I somehow can't see how I can modify the function.

Comment: I think the only problem is the `return []`.  That doesn't belong there as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I need to add that `return []` statement because of the requirement at the bottom of the challenge. The function delivers all required outcomes, the only problem is that it times out for long arrays.

Comment: @PiotrBerebecki Does it time out when you only call `icombinations()`, or when you iterate the result? Also, how long are these "long arrays"?

Comment: @Gothdo I've console.logged the length of the `arr` and it is `50`. When testing the function I only get the message that `Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete`. Not sure how they are testing it in details. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get better suggestions on Code Review, but one improvement you can try is to prune some of the "dead-end" recursive paths. Since you know that each result must be length `k`, you should only recurse when you have enough elements left in the source array to actually complete a k-subset.

```
function* icombinations(arr, k) {

    function* getCombinations(newArr, shift) {
        if (newArr.length === k) {
            yield newArr;
        } 
        // if what's available is >= what's needed
        else if (arr.length - shift >= k - newArr.length) {
            for (let i = shift; i < arr.length; i++) {
                yield* getCombinations([...newArr, arr[i]], i + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    yield* getCombinations([], 0);

    return [];
}
```

But without your test cases or limits on `arr.length` and `k`, we can't know if this is good enough. You mentioned that `arr.length` could be 50, which means a maximum of 126,410,606,437,752 subsets when `k` is 25. No algorithm no matter how efficient will complete that in any reasonable amount of time. Even when `k` is 5 (or equivalently, 45), you're looking at 2,118,760 combinations.

Another thing you could try is to pre-allocate the subset array (`newArr`) outside of the inner function and then update the array in-place prior to each recursive invocation. This avoids the need to copy `newArr` each time you want to append a value to it, but you will still need to yield a copy of `newArr` in your base case. This, however, is more of a micro-optimization compared to the branch-pruning. Try the pruning first by itself to see how much of improvement each change makes.

Finally, you could also switch to an iterative implementation and see if that works.